# WPF streaming Bitmap data into an Image control across threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application, and am streaming a camera frame from an opencv DLL into an `Image` control inside a UserControl.

This works for a while, and then crashes, giving me:

`The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

My code is as follows:

The class that calls the image: (running in a thread)

```
  private void imageShow()
        {        
            while (true)
            {
                if (status == 1)
                {                  
                    IntPtr ptr = getFrame(); // The DLL function that returns the image.
                    imgHalfSize = new Bitmap(640, 360, 3 * 640, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, ptr);

                    CameraFrame = ToBitmapSource(imgHalfSize);

                    CameraFrame.Freeze();
                    Thread.Sleep(20);

                }
         }
```

//conversion from Bitmap to BitmapSource

```
public BitmapSource CameraFrame;

[DllImport("gdi32")]
private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(Bitmap source)
{

    IntPtr ptr = source.GetHbitmap(); //obtain the Hbitmap

    BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
        ptr,
        IntPtr.Zero,
        Int32Rect.Empty,
        System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

    DeleteObject(ptr); //release the HBitmap
    return bs;

}
```

//The userControl that displays the image:

//xaml

```
   <Image Name="ImageCameraFrame"/>
```

cs:

```
  public FormCameraViewFull(DllFunctions _Dense)
        {
            Dense = _Dense; // The class as above
            InitializeComponent();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                InvokeMethodExample();
            });
        }
```

//thread function:

```
 private void InvokeMethodExample()
        {
            while (true)
            {

                ImageCameraFrame.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => ImageCameraFrame.Source = Dense.CameraFrame));
            }
        }
```

As above, this works great for some time, then crashes. I was under the impression that the line `CameraFrame.Freeze();` should stop this behavior, but I am clearly doing something wrong. Do I need a mutex, or similar lock here?

Thank you.

Comment: Remove all occurences of `while (true)` from your code. Besides that, why are you creating a Bitmap from the raw pixel buffer, just to immediately convert it into a BitmapSource, when you could as well directly create a BitmapSource from the pixel data?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. If I remove the` while(true)`, the image does not show at all...

Comment: What's the sense? If you want to repeatedly display a new frame, use a timer, e.g. a DispatcherTimer. These loops without delay are killing you application.

Comment: Replaced with DispatcherTimer, and the crash seems to have disappeared. I assume this is because the timer runs on the UI thread, where i was trying to pass the Bitmap data across multiple threads, without safety.  Thank you very much!

Comment: .. Back to your initial reply... Can I create a BitmapSource the same way? I am new to WPF (obviously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a DispatcherTimer with (an optionally async) Tick handler:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer
{
    Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)
};

timer.Tick += async (s, e) =>
{
    ImageCameraFrame.Source = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var data = Dense.getFrame();
        var format = PixelFormats.Rgb24;
        var width = 640;
        var height = 360;
        var stride = (width * format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
        var bitmap = BitmapSource.Create(width, height, 96, 96,
            format, null, data, stride * height, stride);
        bitmap.Freeze();
        return bitmap;
    });
};

timer.Start();
```

Comment: Thank you! This crashes on `var Bitmap = ...` with ` Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.`

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the buffer size or stride. I can't test it because I don't have your image data provider.

Comment: Ah got it, I need to wait for the camera to spin up before I start the timer. Working great. Thank you again for your time. Much appreciated.